# How to make the carousel a full page image background in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this:

[OneByOne jQuery Slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/full_screen_preview/684613)

I want the sliders to take the entire *width* of the page.  I realize that the size of the image is the same as it displays but each slide is contained in a  tag.  If I remove the parent container then each image does take the entire width but at the end of the last slide the entire slider disappears and after 3 seconds it begins again.

How can I achieve this?

I want to make it look like this: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html#

Except that in my example the header navigation covers the top part and then the image below takes the width of the page.

Comment: Be very careful when doing this. Why would you want to just blow it up to the whole page? Some UX people might frown upon this.

Comment: I call answering this one. 0.0

Comment: @iancarroll my bad! I want to use it because my design looks better with full page images.

Comment: Nice long answer there. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 3):

After digging through the source, you might see how they did it. They used a custom css snippet, which I've pasted below. After that, put the navbar in a div with the class of navbar-wrapper, paste navbar, and close the div. Put the carousel in a div with the classes of carousel and slide, and put an id of your choice. Example code and CSS below.

---

### Carousel Code

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="../assets/img/examples/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
```

---

### CSS Code

```
<style>

    /* GLOBAL STYLES
    -------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

    body {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      color: #5a5a5a;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
    .navbar-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: -90px; /* Negative margin to pull up carousel. 90px is roughly margins and height of navbar. */
    }
    .navbar-wrapper .navbar {

    }

    /* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
    .navbar .navbar-inner {
      border: 0;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
         -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
              box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    }

    /* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
    .navbar .brand {
      padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }

    /* Navbar links: increase padding for taller navbar */
    .navbar .nav > li > a {
      padding: 15px 20px;
    }

    /* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
    .navbar .btn-navbar {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 500px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }



    /* MARKETING CONTENT
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
    .marketing .span4 {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .marketing h2 {
      font-weight: normal;
    }
    .marketing .span4 p {
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }


    /* Featurettes
    ------------------------- */

    .featurette-divider {
      margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
    }
    .featurette {
      padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
      overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
    }
    .featurette-image {
      margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
    }

    /* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
    .featurette-image.pull-left {
      margin-right: 40px;
    }
    .featurette-image.pull-right {
      margin-left: 40px;
    }

    /* Thin out the marketing headings */
    .featurette-heading {
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
    }



    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .container.navbar-wrapper {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      .navbar-inner {
        border-radius: 0;
        margin: -20px 0;
      }

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .navbar-inner {
        margin: -20px;
      }

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
    </style>
```

---

### Navbar Code

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- Read about Bootstrap dropdowns at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->

      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div>
```

**I didn't write the above code. It's for reference from an example template.**

Comment: Wow, thanks @iancarroll.  Let me examine this and see how I can do it on my end. Thanks again!

Comment: The code I have from the plugin is a bit different so I am having trouble finding commonality between the two and what to edit/replace.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this to your `css` codes:

```
.carousel-caption {
  top: 30%;
}
```

You can change `30%` to any percentage you like to make the caption vertically center.